# How to translate label in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, language-translation

I have added search box on header in my website. Using typo3 default search form in Typo3 7LTS latest version with compability6 it's working fine. I want to change label (next and pre) in german page on search result output.

[image: Form elements screenshot]

Comment: I would suggest "weiter" as next and "zurück" as pre.

Comment: Thanks yes Right!
but where should i change it?.

Comment: No, sorry. I have no idea about typo3. I just speak German and thought you are asking about the translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most labels of TYPO3 itself have been translated already. You can download the translations in the ADMIN TOOLS > Languages. Click on the (+) icon for German, click on the download all icon in the top bar (you'll see a progress bar with each selected language). This should download all available labels in German for all installed extensions, activated system extensions and the core.

If you have your frontend correctly configured the German labels will be used if the frontend language is German.

Comment: Thanks. yes i have try to this but locallang.xlf in compability6 extension file not translated in german.

Comment: You can always override and translate labels with the method described at http://xavier.perseguers.ch/en/tutorials/typo3/articles/managing-localization-files.html#c962

Comment: I have try to this code but not getting success...

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['locallangXMLOverride']['EXT:compatibility6/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf'][]
    = 'EXT:website_template/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf';

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['locallangXMLOverride']['de']
    ['EXT:compatibility6/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf'][] = 'EXT:website_template/Resources/Private/Language/de.locallang.xlf';

Comment: Did you empty the language cache (typo3temp/Cache/Data/l10n) ?